# What is the difference between Type[] and [Type] while defining mongoose entity Prop in nestjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema, nestjs-mongoose

I am using following code to define a mongodb entity.

```
@Schema({})
export class User extends BaseModel {
    @Prop({ type: [String], required: true })
    subjects: string[]; // line 1
    // subjects: [string]; // line 2
  
}
```

What is the difference between line 1 and line 2 for defining a mongodb entity property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Mongoose SchemaTypes Documentation for Arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays), the type definition `Type[]` and `[Type]` are interchangeable. You could also use `Array<Type>`. They are essentially all the same internally.